# ¿IDE para programar Python?

Tags: python, ide

Cuales IDEs me recomiendan para programar Python de manera organizada y que tengan su propio compilador para probar el programa ahí adentro del Software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El que te recomiendo es PyCharm, es de la empresa JetBrains y me parece el IDE por excelencia para Python, lo puedes descargar en su versión Community gratis [aquí](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de acuerdo con @Juan Sebastián Vargas

Te recomiendo estos 2 Editores de código, que son compatibles con Python.

[Atom](https://atom.io/)
es un editor de código, gratuito y código abierto, desarrollado por la misma GitHub, tiene como características: Git totalmente integrado, resaltado de sintaxis para distintos lenguajes de programación, tienda de plugins y extensiones, Trabajo en equipo (Gracias a Git, y al modo de equipo (Algo así se llamaba), es un modo donde varios compañeros editan el código a la misma vez), entre otros. Esta disponible en GNU/Linux (64 Bits, aunque hay una versión de terceros para 32 Bits), Windows 7+ (32 y 64 Bits), y Mac OS.

Desventaja: Si tienes una PC con pocos recursos, Atom consume bastante.

[Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3)
es un editor de código, gratuito y de Paga, no es software libre ni código abierto, la versión gratuita no tiene fecha de caducidad (Es como WinRAR). Entre sus características tenemos: resaltado de sintaxis para distintos lenguajes de programación, ligero, versión portable (Esta solo para Windows, aunque con Wine en GNU/Linux no se si corre), fecha de caducidad infinita para la versión gratuita, mini mapa del código que se esta escribiendo, consola de python, entre otros. A diferencia de Atom, este no consume prácticamente nada. Esta disponible en GNU/Linux (32 Bits y 64 Bits), Windows (32 Bits y 64 Bits), Mac OS X y tiene versión portable (Solo para Windows, aunque con Wine en GNU/Linux no se si corre).

Desventaja: La tienda de plugins y extensiones se tiene que instalar aparte.